# Вопрос по синтаксису regex

Tags: c#

Как поместить переменную word в строку reg?
reg это патерн по которому будет вестись поиск в строке str
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings#string-interpolation).

Comment: Код здесь вставляют текстом, а не скринами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Своим кодом вы по сути дублируете переменную `word`. Достаточно будет передавать это переменную `word` в нужный вам метод регулярного выражения.

```
Regex.Match(str,word);
```

Или

```
Regex.IsMatch(str,word);
```

Или создать переменную типа `Regex`

```
Regex reg = new Regex(word);
```

И затем уже работать с ней.